# Calling function within the same namespace

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm building a validation module in javascript and want to call certain validation functions based on a data-attribute on the input-element.

So the function to call is a variable, and I'm used to call said function like: `window[var_name]()`

But in a moduled environment this does not seem to work; If i outplace said function in a different module and import it; it works; but preferably I want thos functions and their logic within the validation module.

```
//--- ./validation.js

// importing common functions
import * as common from './common.js';

export function validateInput($el)
{
  let type = $el.data('validation-type').split('|');
  let val = $el.val();

  // some whitelisting logic
  // and traversing the type-array
  var functionName = 'valid_'+type[i]; // eg valid_email

  // This works if I place the `valid_email()` function in common.js
  var result = common[functionName](val); 

}

function valid_email(val)
{
   // some validation logic
   return true;
}
```

So outplacing the function to its own common.js and importing/namespacing it as common works; as it uses its (common) namespace.

But how would I be able to call the function within the same module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the function to a object and call it like this:

```
    //--- ./validation.js

// importing common functions
import * as common from './common.js';

export function validateInput($el)
{
let type = $el.data('validation-type').split('|');
let val = $el.val();

// some whitelisting logic
// and traversing the type-array
var functionName = valid[type[i]]; // valid.email() below

// how the call looks now
var result = functionName(val); 

}

var valid = {
    email: function(val) {
        // some validation logic
        return true;
    }
}
```